# Use composer to load custom classes

Tags: php, plugin-development, composer

I want to use composer to load my custom classes inside my plugin. I've tried to use it but without success. Is possible to use compose for the plugin develop to manage custom classes used inside it? Can anyone point me into the roght direction?

Comment: How exactly is your WordPress project been set up? From a Composer template? And now you want to autoload project dependencies in your plugin? Or does your plugin have a composer.json and you want to autoload dependencies there? Did googling for "wordpress autoload plugin" shed any lights on your issue?

Comment: Are you trying to set up and use an autoloader for your plugin? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @leymannx I want to use composer to load the plugin classes. for now I'm requiring classes using `require_once`, this is not the best option because the plugin will become more modular in the future. @TomJNowell Yes, the autoloader will be used only internally from the plugin

Comment: An autoloader and composer are not the same thing. Composer includes an autoloader, but is mainly a PHP package manager. If you want to autoload classes that belong to the plugin, and not a separate package, then you don't need composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context from you, I can only assume and show you what I have done that works for me using PSR4 Autoloading.

#### Example:

Assuming that all my custom class directories and files is in **./inc** folder

In your composer.json, add this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Inc\\": "./inc"  
    }
}
```

**Inc** is the vendor name of your application, use this for namspacing files inside your **inc** directory like `namespace Inc/Api;`

**./inc** is the directory(with all the class files or nested directory) you want to autoload.

Next, do this in your terminal to generate the vendor directory & autoload the files.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Lastly, require the the autoloading by adding this to your plugin file *eg. my-awesome-plugin.php*

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

Comment: For now after some researches I've understand that the composer isn't the best choice for wordpress. I'm developing a plugin that I want to expand with other classes. I will try your example. I need to setup the namespace for all my custo, class like this `vendor/ClassName` right?

Comment: For example, if you have **Inc** folder at your root and nested within it is folder **Api**, and both _Food.php_ & _Drink.php_ is inside **Api**.

In both of your class _Food.php_ and _Drink.php_, you declare them at the top like this `namespace Inc\Api;`

To use them, you declare them like this `use Inc\Api\Food` (assuming your class name is same as file name) on other files.