# Use Composer Package inside class - Namespacing error

Tags: functions, composer, namespace

I have my theme, with a folder called classes, with a single class:

```
wp-content
|- themes
   |- mycustomtheme
      |- classes
         |- FooBar.php
```

In FooBar, I would like to use this package here: [Soundasleep / HTML2Text](https://packagist.org/packages/soundasleep/html2text).

And use it like this:

**In FooBar.php**

```
  doSomethingBadass( $some_html ){
    wp_mail( 'b@b.com', 'test', \Soundasleep\Html2Text::convert( $some_html ) );
  }
```

But whatever I do, I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Soundasleep\Html2Text' not found in /app/public/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/classes/FooBar.php:60

---

**My attempt**

I assume that it's something to do with the namespacing.

I'm including `FooBar.php` by requiring the class in the functions.php.

How do I get past this?
And if possible, then please link to a documentation or a place where I could have figured this out. I've been on this for 2 hours now.

---

**Update**

I'm including Composer with these lines inside `functions.php`:

```
if( file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php' ) ){
    require get_template_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

Comment: How are you including that package? You mentioned Composer, so does your theme have a composer.json file and a vendor directory? Have you included the vendor/autoload.php file?

Comment: I updated the question with the info.

Comment: Where/how is `doSomethingBadass()` used?

Comment: In `/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/inc/some-other-file.php` ... And I've included that in functions.php. Should I set a namespace in there? Or write: `use Soundasleep\Html2Text` in there?

Comment: Is your theme a child theme? Have you confirmed that the package supports auto-loading, and that the autoloader is indeed loaded? Are you loading the autoloader before everything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use composer to load custom classes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/349946/use-composer-to-load-custom-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses the conditional:

```
if( file_exists())
```

So are you sure you are using the correct path to `autoload.php` as it will stop if not found and you won't get the usual error thrown by `require`?

Personally I'd be expecting to see your vendor dir outside of the wordpress install.

Comment: Moving the Vendor-directory fixed it, so I reference the `html2text` like so: `\Soundasleep\Html2Text::convert( $some_html )`. So for anyone else... Move composer.json to the root, so the vendor-directory will be there as well.